# Zoom Polls: Why do I not see the option?

Tags: technology, video-conference

I have a Zoom paid account ("Pro") and from googling it seems that the polling option should be available to me.

However when I start a meeting I do not seem to see the option to start a poll. Any clue what I may be doing wrong? Do other see the polling option in free / paid zoom versions?

And in Settings for my account I do See that the Meeting Polls option is already enabled (screenshot below).

Not sure what I am doing wrong!

The use case is that I wanted to ask live questions during my lecture to gauge whether students have understood a concept.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem once. It worked for me once I had a poll prepared in advance (in the Zoom web portal before the meeting starts).

Comment: This was it! Thanks! A bit silly that they won't allow you to create it on the fly via the zoom app.